# Dealing with data attributes in weka jython

Tags: java, python-3.x, weka, jython, jfreechart

I am using [jython](/questions/tagged/jython) on [weka](/questions/tagged/weka), and my goal is to visualize my data with a time horizon; so for that I need to get the date attribute and play a little with it. I will like to know if it is possible to do that in [jython](/questions/tagged/jython) interface; I tried for example to print the particular attribute but it keeps yelling at me. For example:

```
# load data file
file = FileReader("C:/file_path/file_name.arff")
data = Instances(file)
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1)

print(data)
```

output:

```
@relation file_name

@attribute dates date dd/mm/yyyy

*...etc*
```

Another example:

```
# load data file
file = FileReader("C:/file_path/file_name.arff")
data = Instances(file)
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1)

print(data.dates)
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\file_path\untitled", line 26, in <module>
AttributeError: 'weka.core.Instances' object has no attribute 'dates'
```

Answer (score 0):

While "dates" isn't an attribute of the "data" object, you may simply output the data using the code below:

```
# load data file
file = FileReader("C:/file_path/file_name.arff")
data = Instances(file)
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1)

for i in data:
    print i
```